# Possible bug with code block horizontal scroll bar

Tags: discussion, support, bug, suggested-edits, code-formatting

I was going through the suggested edits and I got [this suggested edit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/8782952) where the code ran right to the edge of the code block.  The code block has a horizontal scroll bar so I went to drag it to see what else there was but when I do that the whole code block starts flashing as I move the mouse left or right.  If I stop scrolling when there is no code being displayed in the code block disappears and will not come back until you scroll again

Before scrolling:

[image]

After scrolling:

[image]

I don't know if the narrower code block is causing this issue or if is the fact that the code runs right to the edge of the block.  The second code block does not have this issue.

I am using Windows 7 pro SP1 with Google Chrome Version 43.0.2357.132 m.  My monitor is 19" and is set to 1440 x 900

Comment: Which OS and browser? I don't see this problem with Windows and Firefox.

Comment: @DavidPostill I updated to question with that information.

Comment: I'm able to reproduce with Windows 8.1, Chrome 43.0.2357.130 m. Tried to repro in Firefox but the horizontal scroll bar doesn't appear.

Comment: Yeah I tried with my Firefox and I couldn't get the scroll bar unless I zoomed in.

Comment: No repro with Firefox 39.0 or Chromium 43.0.2357.130 on Linux. I do get scroll bars, but they function perfectly normally.

Comment: Update: I *can* repro this on Chromium by opening developer tools and manually adjusting the width of the `<pre>` block to be *exactly one pixel narrower* than the content. For me, this is 475px. At 474px, the bug does not occur; at 476px, the scroll bar disappears. I'm inclined to call this a Chrome bug.

Comment: @IlmariKaronen Can you still repro it?

Comment: @wizzwizz4: Not using the instructions I gave above (or minor variations of them) with Chrome 73 on MacOS. Then again, this is a completely different laptop with a different OS and different fonts, so I'm not surprised. That said, a bunch of these rounding bugs seem to have been fixed as a side effect of Chrome's [LayoutNG](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=591099) project, and this may well be one of them.